# count words in latex files with input

Tags: texcount

Hi is there something like `texcount` to count all the words of a latex file including the ones linked by `input` and `include`?

Solution for linux as well as for windows are fine for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TeXcount can include subfiles included by `\input`, `\include` or the `subfiles` package. For this, you need to use the option `-inc` which will automatically parse the subfiles, or `-merge` which will merge the included subfiles into the main document.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you: `texcount inhalt.tex -inc -total` was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I've tried `texcount main.tex` with no result: no words counted. Is there a simpler and complete way to execute this command?

Comment: Does it fail to execute, or does it execute but return a zero count?

Answer (score 3):

Save this script as `buildFile.pl` and run it with Perl or execute it: `buildFile.pl < main.tex > mainTotal.tex`. Then you have one TeX document which can use texcount or something else. However, sometimes it is easier to create a pdf and count the words with other tools, like `pdftotext <file>.pdf - | wc -w`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
##################################################
# build one main file
# (C) 2005 Herbert Voss
##################################################
#
#use strict;
# 
# call with
# 
# ./buildFile.pl main.tex > mainTotal.tex
# 
# in the mainTotal.tex will be comments all starting
# with %%% which will not be of interest
# 

sub p_inc {
  $fileName = shift;
    if ( open (my $file, "$fileName.tex") ) {
      print "%%%---------- open: ", $fileName, "\n";
      while (<$file>) {
        if ((/^\s*\\include{\s+(\S+)/i) or (/^\s*\\input{\s+(\S+)/i)) {
          my $include = $1;
          chomp($include);chop($include);
          print "%%%%%%%%% jump to ", $include, "\n";
          p_inc($include);
        } else { print unless /^\s*(#|$)/; }
      }
      print "%%%---------- close: ", $fileName, "\n";
      close $file;
    } else { print "%%%<===== file does'n exist\n"; }
}
#
@lines = (<>);
for $line (@lines) {
  next if $line =~ /^\s*(%)/;
  if (($line =~ /^\s*\\include{\s*(\S+)/i) or ($line =~ /^\s*\\input{\s*(\S+)/i)) {
    my $include = $1;
    chomp($include);
    chop($include);
    print "%%%%%%%%%%% jump to ", $include, "\n";
    p_inc($include);
  } else { print $line; }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about pdftotext. This works like a charm. It does however also count stuff like toc,tof,...

Comment: @magu_ There are options `-f` `-l` for `pdftotext`, you can give the page range and you can exclude toc, tof etc. by this way.

Comment: Herbert. This works. It is a very nice way to characterize also non latex files. However I feel a bit more comfortable with the texcount answer, since it does this natively. But thank you anyway since you made me learn something new.